# how do i customize underline code in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I use to write textDecorationLine:'underline' but it doesn't look quite good in my app, I need help to make decorate underline on text.
Thank YOu !

Answer (score 1):

What looks bad to you might look good to other, please make sure to be more specific in future.

As to per your question, there's a few decorationstyles you can apply. Below is an example:

```
<Text style={styles.sampleStyle} >Something </Text>

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sampleStyle: {
    textDecorationLine: "underline",
    textDecorationStyle: "solid",
    textDecorationColor: "#000"
  }
});
```

For further reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text